# Calculate the minute under same name using sql

Tags: sql

Let's say a table A

```
Name.   Date.         Time
ABC    20-12-2020   10:10:00
ABC    20-12-2020   10:10:10
ABC    20-12-2020   10:10:10
ABC    20-12-2020   12:10:11
CDE    22-12-2020   07:10:01
```

I want to calculate the minute under same name and date.

Required output

```
Name.   Date.         Time.    O/P
ABC    20-12-2020   10:10:00  1
ABC    20-12-2020   10:10:10  1
ABC    20-12-2020   10:10:20  1
ABC    20-12-2020   12:10:11  2
CDE    22-12-2020   07:10:01  1
```

I tried row-num partition by, but it is not giving required results.

Starting 3 rows of o/p column is 1 because it's of same minute, date and name.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: the fourth row is also the same minute, date and name.

Answer (score 0):

You want `dense_rank()` with the date/time truncated down to the minute level.

The date time functions vary by databases.  Here is an example, using standard syntax:

```
select a.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by name
                          order by date,
                                   extract(hour from time),
                                   extract(minute from time)
                         )
from a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need partition by same hour
With rank()

```
    Select Name, Date, Time, 
    rank() over partition by
     (name, Date, To_char(time, 'hh')
       order
      By name, date) as o/p from table
```